# Using a download handler to save ggplot images in shiny

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I am developing an application in shiny.In shiny, I am rendering a simple plot using the action button. I have included a download button to download the the plot that is now in UI. from my  code(plot3)

I tried the below code, to save the image, but I am getting an error

> plotInput not found.

Could any one suggest where i am going wrong.

Below is my code for reference.
UI:

```
ui <- tabItem(tabName = "models2",
        fluidPage(
          fluidRow(
            infoBoxOutput("overview")
          ),
          fluidRow(
            actionButton("result1","Generate Result"),
            downloadButton('downloadPlot','Download Plot'),
            plotOutput("plot3")
          )
        ))
```

SERVER

```
server <- function(input,output,session{
 output$overview <- renderValueBox({
      valueBox(
        paste("91"),"Overview",icon=icon("hourglass"),
        color="green"
      )
    })
  observeEvent(input$result1,{
  output$plot3  <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(data=timedata, aes(x=dat1, y=yes, group=3))+ 
      geom_point(shape=1)+
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(dat1_xlowlim,dat1_xhighlim))+
      labs(title="Probability",x="Date",y="True probability")  
  })
  })
  output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function(){paste(input$plot3,'.png',sep='')},
    content = function(plot3){
      ggsave(plot3,plotInput())

    }
  )
})
```

Also, to note my shiny and R studio are in R environment.

Comment: typo in labs(title="Probability",x="Date",y="True probability")

Comment: @A.Suliman I will corect it now. Though I am getting the plot, the problem is  i am not able to downlaod the plot

Comment: First you have the close parentheses after args of server function. Then you will get  `Warning: Error in plotInput: could not find function "plotInput"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
ui <- tabItem(tabName = "models2",
          fluidPage(
            fluidRow(
              infoBoxOutput("overview")
            ),
            fluidRow(
              actionButton("result1","Generate Result"),
              downloadButton('downloadPlot','Download Plot'),
              plotOutput("plot3")
            )
          ))

server <- function(input,output,session){
           output$overview <- renderValueBox({
           valueBox(
            paste("91"),"Overview",icon=icon("hourglass"),
           color="green"
      )
  })
    data <- reactiveValues()
    observeEvent(input$result1,{
    data$plot <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width))+ 
    geom_point(shape=1)})

    output$plot3  <- renderPlot({  data$plot })

    output$downloadPlot <- downloadHandler(
         filename = function(){paste("input$plot3",'.png',sep='')},
         content = function(file){
          ggsave(file,plot=data$plot)
    }
  )
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: @Suliman, I can download the image.But then the app closes automatically. I want it to be running.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what you mean by app closes automatically. I run the app in Rstudio and in web browser and nothing unusual happens after downloading.

Answer (score 2):

@Mikz
I don't have enough reputation to follow your comment. Thus, I create a new anwser but wish to answer your question 'why app closes automatically?'.

I had same issue when I develop shiny app on rstudio-server of my company. My app will close by itself after a while. However, same app run on my local laptop don't have this issue.

After my research, I believe it caused by timeout setting (default is 60 seconds). I also use function ~~Sys.sleep()~~ to test this default time. I found the solution works for me from this [blog](https://tickets.dominodatalab.com/hc/en-us/articles/360015932932-Increasing-the-timeout-for-Shiny-Server) .

The idea is using WebSocket to trigger app every 50 seconds. In this way, you don't need to ask technique guy to adjust setting on server level.

Comment: Take a look again at [answer]. By posting something that isn't an answer, you risk getting downvoted, which makes you lose rep, which puts you *further* away from the goal of having enough rep to comment

Comment: Thank you so much@camille for your reminder. I admit my answer is not related to the main question above. My purpose is to help Mikz since I faced the same error but I have fixed it with a solution. Since the person who ask the main question is also @Mikz, I hope my solution can help his follow-up question. Anyway, I will follow our community's rules in the future with my purpose/goal is to share and help each other.