# How to download ggplot as png with downloadHandler? Currently I am getting multiple errors

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, download

I am having issues with downloading my ggplot as a png file. My ggplot has a click function so when you click in the plot, the order of the plot changes so therefor I have an if and else condition in my renderPlot output. Below is part of the server code:

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({   

    e <- as.character(input$AB1)
    k <- TCGA(e) #function for cancer data
    g <- MEANSD(e) #function for healthy data
    test <- rbind(k,g) #combine healthy with cancer data 
    test$Tissue <- as.factor(test$Tissue) #row names of graph as factor -- important to order the graph according to alphabet or value of expression

    if (plot_data$trigger %% 2 == 0) {
      gg1 <- ggplot(test, aes(x= test$Origin , y= as.numeric(test$r), fill = Can))+geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour = "grey") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ggtitle(as.character(input$AB1)) + labs(y = "Expression level in log2(tpm+0.001) scale", x = "Tissue type (alphabetical order)")
    gg1
      } else {
      ggplot(test, aes(x= reorder(test$Origin, -test$r, sum) , y= as.numeric(test$r), fill = Can))+geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour = "grey") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ggtitle(as.character(input$AB1)) +  labs(y = "Expression level in log2(tpm+0.001) scale", x = "Tissue type (expression level order)")

      }
     })

output$tumordown <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function () {
      paste(input$AB1, "png", sep = ".")
    },
    content = function (file) {

      ggsave(file, plot = gg1)

      dev.off()
    }
  )
```

This code above gives me the error 
*Saving 5.76 x 4 in image
Warning: Error in ggsave: object 'gg1' not found
  [No stack trace available]*

```
ggsave(file, plot = ggplot(test, aes(x= test$Origin , y= as.numeric(test$r), fill = Can))+geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour = "grey") + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + ggtitle(as.character(input$AB1)) + labs(y = "Expression level in log2(tpm+0.001) scale", x = "Tissue type (alphabetical order)")
```

and this code gives me: *Saving 6.67 x 6.67 in image
Warning: Error in : You're passing a function as global data.
Have you misspelled the `data` argument in `ggplot()`
  [No stack trace available]*

My first question: does anyone know how to get around this error? I have checked out many examples on this site but it still gives me the errors. 
My second question: in case the downloading will work, is it possible to save the if and else conditional plots in one png?

Many many thanks for the help!

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible example, with some example data?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49977969/using-a-download-handler-to-save-ggplot-images-in-shiny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your ggplot graphic in a reactive conductor:

```
gg1 <- reactive({
  e <- as.character(input$AB1)
  k <- TCGA(e) #function for cancer data
  g <- MEANSD(e) #function for healthy data
  test <- rbind(k,g) #combine healthy with cancer data 
  test$Tissue <- as.factor(test$Tissue) #row names of graph as factor -- important to order the graph according to alphabet or value of expression
  if (plot_data$trigger %% 2 == 0) {
    gg <- ggplot(test, aes(x = test$Origin , y = as.numeric(test$r), fill = Can)) + 
      geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour = "grey") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
      ggtitle(as.character(input$AB1)) + 
      labs(y = "Expression level in log2(tpm+0.001) scale", 
           x = "Tissue type (alphabetical order)")
  } else {
    gg <- ggplot(test, 
                 aes(x = reorder(test$Origin, -test$r, sum), 
                     y = as.numeric(test$r), 
                     fill = Can)) + 
      geom_bar(position = position_dodge(), stat="identity", colour = "grey") + 
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) + 
      ggtitle(as.character(input$AB1)) +
      labs(y = "Expression level in log2(tpm+0.001) scale", 
           x = "Tissue type (expression level order)")
  }
  gg
})
```

Then

```
output$plot1 <- renderPlot({ gg1() })
```

And in the `downloadHandler`:

```
ggsave(file, gg1())
```

And remove `dev.off()`.

Comment: Thank you very much!